# engine.io [RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded]

Tags: socket.io, engine.io

Randomly getting the **RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded** when send the data to connected client(s) via Socket.IO room concept. Gone through few forums it is stating that the data object may have *self-referencing array* [Node.js + Socket.io Maximum call stack size exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27376522/node-js-socket-io-maximum-call-stack-size-exceededdue) this exception may occurs but in my code I getting the exception in both the plain string data & data object also.

*Below are the sample code snips*

*Sending plain text*

```
socket.emit('STATUS','OK');
```

*Stack Trace*

```
Error in SendPlainText : RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at TLSSocket.Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:1:1)
    at TLSSocket.Socket._write (net.js:783:8)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:397:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:383:5)
    at TLSSocket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:290:11)
    at TLSSocket.Socket.write (net.js:707:40)
    at Sender.sendFrame (/node_v0_10_36/node_modules/ws/lib/Sender.js:390:20)
    at Sender.send (/node_v0_10_36/node_modules/ws/lib/Sender.js:312:12)
    at WebSocket.send (/node_v0_10_36/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:377:18)
    at send (/node_v0_10_36/node_modules/engine.io/lib/transports/websocket.js:114:17)
```

***Sending object data***

```
var clients = socketio.sockets.adapter.rooms['ROOMID'];

if(clients != undefined && clients != null)
{
    console.log('Sending data to client');
    socketio.sockets.in('ROOMID').emit('DATA', data);
}
```

*Stack Trace*

```
Error in SendData : RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at /node_v0_10_36/node_modules/engine.io-parser/lib/index.js:236:12
    at proxy (/node_v0_10_36/node_modules/after/index.js:23:13)
    at /node_v0_10_36/node_modules/engine.io-parser/lib/index.js:255:7
    at /node_v0_10_36/node_modules/engine.io-parser/lib/index.js:231:7
    at Object.exports.encodePacket (/node_v0_10_36/node_modules/engine.io-parser/lib/index.js:79:10)
    at encodeOne (/node_v0_10_36/node_modules/engine.io-parser/lib/index.js:230:13)
    at map (/node_v0_10_36/node_modules/engine.io-parser/lib/index.js:253:5)
    at Object.exports.encodePayload (/node_v0_10_36/node_modules/engine.io-parser/lib/index.js:235:3)
    at XHR.Polling.send (/node_v0_10_36/node_modules/engine.io/lib/transports/polling.js:246:10)
    at Socket.flush (/node_v0_10_36/node_modules/engine.io/lib/socket.js:431:20)
```