Maximum call stack size exceeded using socket.io-client
I've exceeded the maximum call stack size using socket.io-client
I tried everything even tried using ws and still end up with the same error.
Using Node.js v22.2.0

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at [nodejs.internal.kHybridDispatch] (node:internal/event_target:824:9)
at WebSocket.dispatchEvent (node:internal/event_target:751:26)
at fireEvent (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:10966:14)
at failWebsocketConnection (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11040:9)
at WebSocket.close (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11650:11)
at WS.doClose (C:\Users\User\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\lib\transports\websocket.js:248:13)
at Transport.close (C:\Users\User\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\lib\transport.js:98:10)
at Socket.onClose (C:\Users\User\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\lib\socket.js:713:20)
at Socket.onError (C:\Users\User\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\lib\socket.js:691:8)
at WS. (C:\Users\User\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\lib\socket.js:281:10)

async function initSocket() {
    console.log("Connecting to websocket...");

    try {
        const userData = (await axios.get(`https://${domain}/api/v2/metadata/socket`)).data;
        
        const socket = io(
            socketEndpoint,
            {
                transports: ["websocket"],
                secure: true,
                rejectUnauthorized: false,
                reconnect: true,
                extraHeaders: { 'User-agent': `${userData.user.id} API Bot` }
            }
        );

        socket.on('connect', async () => {
            console.log(`Connected to websocket`);

            socket.on('init', (data) => {
                if (data && data.authenticated) {
                    console.log(`Successfully authenticated as ${data.name}`);

                    socket.emit('filters', {
                        price_max: 9999999
                    });

                } else {
                    socket.emit('identify', {
                        uid: userData.user.id,
                        model: userData.user,
                        authorizationToken: userData.socket_token,
                        signature: userData.socket_signature
                    });
                }
            });

            socket.on('new_item', (data) => {
                console.log(data)
            });
            

            socket.on("close", (reason) => console.log(`Socket closed: ${reason}`));
            socket.on('error', (data) => console.log(`WS Error: ${data}`));
            socket.on('connect_error', (data) => console.log(`Connect Error: ${data}`));
        });

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(`Error while initializing the Socket. Error: ${e}`);
    }
};


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27376522/node-js-socket-io-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded

Tried everything cannot find what is causing it, tried where it doesnt even include any array just strings and still nothing.
